# TYPO3: Allow HTML for Rich Text Editor

Tags: html, typo3, rte, rich-text-editor

The default settings of the RTE only allow some types of HTML elements. I also want to allow

- `form`
- `button`
- `input`

How can I do this? I searched a bit and found this:

```
## RTE configuration
RTE.default {
    proc {
        # tags allowed
        allowTags = table, tbody, tr, th, td, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div, p, br, span, ul, ol, li, re, blockquote, strong, em, b, i, u, sub, sup, strike, a, img, nobr, hr, tt, q, cite, abbr, acronym, center

        # html parser configuration
        HTMLparser_rte {

            # tags allowed
            allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is the right solution ...

Comment: I tried this and it didn't worked ...

Answer (score 2):

You should add the tags you want to the config

```
## RTE configuration
RTE.default {
    proc {
        # tags allowed
        allowTags = table, tbody, tr, th, td, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, div, p, br, span, ul, ol, li, re, blockquote, strong, em, b, i, u, sub, sup, strike, a, img, nobr, hr, tt, q, cite, abbr, acronym, center

        allowTags := addToList(form, button, input) 

        # html parser configuration
        HTMLparser_rte {

            # tags allowed
            allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer of @HerrSerker is almost correct - it adds support of extra tags (*form, button, input*) to RTE, but you also need to allow them at your FE, so the final result should be this:

**Page TS**

```
RTE.default.proc.allowTags := addToList(form, button, input)
RTE.default.proc.entryHTMLparser_db.allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags
RTE.default.proc.allowTagsOutside := addToList(form)
```

*allowTagsOutside* instructs RTE to allow this tag outside of p-tags.

**TS Constants in your TS template**

```
styles.content.links.allowTags := addToList(form, button, input)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Alos You should unset denyTags and to check entryHTMLparser_db subvalues

An example of default RTE configuration could be found [here](http://www.typo3-addict.com/2008/08/my-default-rte-configuration/).

Comment: If I use `denyTags >` all denyTags would be overwritten? I want to keep the standard settings but only allow form, button, input.

Comment: @testing the opposite of addToList is removeFromList. You could use that with denyTags

Comment: @testing You could redefine denyTags, with it's edited default value